# image and kernel of the linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

consider an nxp matrix A and a pxm matrix B. IF ker(A)=im(B), what can you say about the product of AB.

potential answer, please tell me if I am on the right path?

i believe nxp means that A: Rn to Rp and pxm means that B: Rp to Rm
now the image of B, im(B)= Rm since this is where the output is (or it does not necessarily mean it spans the entire Rm) 
then, if the im(B)=ker(A) that means that both are m so AB=m^2 
is this completely ridiculous?

Comment: Normally an $n\times m$ matrix is interpreted as a map from $\mathbb R^m$ to $\mathbb R^n$. So in this case $B:\mathbb R^m\rightarrow\mathbb R^p$ and $A:\mathbb R^p\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$. No relation is necessary between $n,\,m$ and $p$. $\mathrm{im}(B)$ and $\ker(A)$ are subspaces of $\mathbb R^p$ but may not be all of $\mathbb R^p$.

Answer (score 2):

**Definitions**

$im(B)=\{y~:~\exists x~\text{such that}~Bx=y\}$ is the *image* (also often called *range*) of $B$.  I.e. it is the set of possible outputs of $B$.

$\ker(A)=\{x~:~Ax=0\}$ is the *kernel* (also often called *nullspace*) of $A$.  I.e. it is the set of all things which become zero after being acted upon by $A$.

---

Side notes: $\ker(A)$ will be a *subspace* of the domain of $A$ (*possibly equal to but not necessarily equal to the whole domain of $A$*).  If $\ker(A)=domain(A)$, then $Ax=0$ for all $x$ in the domain.  We call that operator the *zero* operator.

Similarly, $im(A)$ will be a *subspace* of the codomain of $A$ (*possibly equal but not necessarily equal to the whole codomain of $A$*).  If $im(A)=codomain(A)$ we call the operator surjective.

---

Now... when $\ker(A)=im(B)$ one has for every $x$ in the domain of $B$ (and hence in the domain of $AB$):

$(AB)x = A(Bx) = \dots$

> Remember that $Bx\in im(B)=\ker(A)$ implying that $ABx=...$

Since this is true for all $x$, what does this say about the transformation $AB$?

---

> The above implies that $(AB)x=A(Bx)= 0$ since $(Bx)\in \ker(A)$.  Since this is true for all $x$ in the domain of $AB$, we see that $AB$ is the zero operator.  $0~:~\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n$

Comment: what i understand is that the image of A is the kernel of B, that is, the codomain of A is the domain of B. but this does not really help me see what happens to (AB)x = since I don't quite understand how they are contained in one another. i know that ker(B) is contained in ker (AB) and im(AB) is contained in im(A) but I don't understand why that is, due to this I believe that I can't answer this question

Comment: @Irina the codomain and the image are **not** the same thing.  The image is a subspace of the codomain, but there can be things in the codomain which are not in the image.  Similarly, the kernel is a *subspace* of the domain, but not necessarily the whole thing.

Comment: so does that mean that the im(A) does not have to equal to ker(B)? since these subspaces might not overlap?

Comment: @Irina The problem statement told us that $im(A)=ker(B)$.  It will not always be this way, but in this specific problem they are telling us that this is the case.  So, since $Bx\in im(B)$ and $im(B)=ker(A)$, we have that $Bx\in ker(A)$.  What does it mean for something to be in $ker(A)$?  What then is $A(Bx)$ equal to?  What then is $(AB)x$ equal to?

Comment: for something to be ker(A) this means that Bx=0 vector does that mean that A(0)=0 so (AB)x=0?

Comment: @Irina $Bx$ doesn't have to be zero, it can be nonzero, but it does mean that $A(Bx)=0$.  For example, the transformations $A([x,y])=[0,y]$ and $B([x,y])=[x,0]$ satisfy the property that $ker(A)=im(B)$.  We have $(AB)[x,y] = A(B[x,y])=A[x,0]=[0,0]$, despite $[x,0]\neq 0$ when $x\neq 0$

Comment: That makes more sense, thank you for your thorough explanation. I was having a difficulty visualizing Bx prior to putting it into the linear transformation form. I had one more question which I was hoping to clarify, when putting a matrix in an rref form this does not necessarily change the properties of the image and the kernel, correct? since they are still the same except in a reduced form, thank you in advance!

Comment: actually now that i think of it the rref of the matrix changes the image but not the kernel, is that correct?

Comment: @Irina See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379719/why-does-the-reduced-row-echelon-form-have-the-same-null-space-as-the-original-m).  The short answer is that by putting a matrix into rref, the kernel is unchanged and the image has the possibility of being changed (*some will have image unchanged and others will have it changed*)