# Does the nullspace of R is the same as the nullspace of U (where R is the row reduced echelon form of A and U is the matrix in LU decomposition of A)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does the nullspace of R is the same as the nullspace of U (where R is the row reduced echelon form of A and U is the matrix in LU decomposition of A)?

What is the proof for this and the intuitive explanation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The null space of the rref of $A$ is the same as the null space of $A$. See this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379719/why-does-the-reduced-row-echelon-form-have-the-same-null-space-as-the-original-m/1379730

Comment: If $A=LU$ (no pivoting), and $L$ is formed as the product of invertible matrices, so that it is invertible, then $Ax=0$ if and only if $LUx=0$ if and only if $Ux=L^{-1}0=0$